# Git command to get pull request subject body from issue number

Tags: github, github-api, gitpython

I would like to get pull request body, subject and URL from issue number by git command especially by gitPython library. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GitPython** is used for `git` related objects whereas a **Pull Request** is **GitHub** related and hence cannot be used to get GitHub data.

You may use **GitHub's v4 GraphQL API** to get the pull request details with the below query

```
query {
  repository(name: "gitPython",owner:"gitpython-developers"){
    pullRequest(number:974){
      body
      title
      url
    }
  }
}
```

The curl request for the above query:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://api.github.com/graphql' \
-H 'Authorization: bearer <token>' \
-H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{"query":"{\n repository(name: \"gitPython\",owner:\"gitpython-developers\"){\n pullRequest(number:974){\n body\n title\n url\n }\n }\n }"'
```

The response for the above request:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequest": {
        "body": "Removed A from Dockerfile that I added accidentally. THIS WILL BREAK THE BUILD",
        "title": "Remove A from Dockerfile",
        "url": "https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/pull/974"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: You need to generate a **token** to access the GraphQL API, which you can generate by following the steps given [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

Alternatively, you can even use **GitHub's v3 API** as below to get the pull request details, which would have the **body**, **title** and **url** fields as part of the response

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repoName}/pulls/{pullRequestNumber}

GET https://api.github.com/repos/gitpython-developers/GitPython/pulls/974
```

Comment: i install github command line interface in terminal and i can get response from `hub api https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo_name}/issues/{issue_number}` but from python code command `subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)` i have `{CalledProcessError}Command 'hub api xxxxx' returned non-zero exit status 2.` any idea?